# Нарисовать линию пути

Tags: unity3d

Есть массив точек ( объявляются в настройках скрипта ), по которым движется объект ( 3d )

Вопрос: каким образом можно провести линию между этими точками, что бы ее было видно при старте игры ( интересует не сам алгоритм, а скорее что использовать в качестве линии: игровые объекты, какие-то графические элементы )

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от формы кривой. Проще всего воспользоваться готовыми объектами в Unity вроде LineRenderer (http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html_), вот только при если точки лежат не в плоскости, толщина линии может искажаться, поэтому в своих проектах я генерировал линии при помощи скрипта. 
Видел в других проектах как делали линии из цилиндров от точки до точки а в самих точках вставляли сферы чтобы сгладить переход. Все зависит от характера кривой, и какую линию вы хотите рисовать. При помощи GL можно рисовать линии в один пиксель, а если надо больше, то лучше делать это уже через Mesh.